# using DATE_ADD from db2 to mysql

Tags: mysql, db2

In my php script i have the following query:

```
SELECT 
     inv as INVOICE,
     shpdate as SHIPDATE
  FROM table1
    WHERE to_date(char(shpdate), 'YYYYMMDD') >= '2018-01-01'
```

which returns records successfully. This is taking a packed value and returning it to match the YYYY-MM-DD format.

I'm trying to add an interval and insert to mysql like so:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1)
    values(DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPDATE, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 127 DAY) as expire_date)
```

But when I run this it says it is not a valid function. I know the query is successful, but the insert is failing, most likely because I'm not using the DATE-ADD correctly for some reason.

Any help on how to change this insert syntax is much appreciated.

Comment: In the mysql target table, what is the column-datatype for expire_date ( i.e. date, timestamp, datetime) ? Mysql DATE_ADD() returns a *string*.

Comment: It's a DATE field

Answer (score 0):

You can also add days to a DATE value like this `SELECT shpdate + 127 DAYS as SHIPDATE FROM table1`.
Also, you can filter on a date column like this `WHERE shpdate >= '2018-01-01'`.
Both those assume that `shpdate` is of datatype DATE

Comment: Also, this is not a DATE datatype, the value I'm selecting is a packed field in DB2, but I'm inserting into a DATE type

Answer (score 0):

Also `DATE_ADD` is not a function in Db2. You probably want to look at `ADD_DAYS()` if you don't want to use the `+ n DAYS` syntax. Please refer to the manual  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061468.html

Comment: True, but like I stated in the question I'm inserting into MySQL. I've used Date_add on this before but I've since altered the original select to use to_date so that I can grab the dates from db2 correctly, but the date_add is used for mysql on the insert, not db2

Comment: Yes, unless you are using Db2 Federation to insert into a Db2 Nickname that resolves to a MySQL table, you will need to use MySQL functions not Db2 ones.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.data.fluidquery.doc/topics/t0070303.html    Federation might be a good option for you (altough it looks like IUD is not currently supported for MySQL) , but if you are not going that route, then I'm not sure you needed to tag this question as relating to db2 at all

Answer (score 0):

If SHIPDATE is a string variable with value in format 'YYYY-MM-DD' and datatype of table(column1) is DATE, then try:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1)
values(date_add(convert(:shipdate,date), interval 127 day));
```